# Как в ansible узнать установленные пакеты через make?

Tags: python, linux, centos, ansible

Через package_facts находятся пакеты установленные через пакетные установщики rpm или yum, но через make не находятся (OS Centos 7). Нужно узнать установлен ли пакет и его версию. Можно ли это как-то сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

через which смотри бинарник исполнимый, а потом узнавай у него версию через выполнение программы с параметром --version.

```
which bash && bash --version | head -1 | cut -f 4 -d ' '
```

Библиотеки, а также и исполняемые файлы, можно проверить через pkg-config

```
[eri@eri-macro ~]$ pkg-config --exists libcrypto --modversion
1.1.1d
[eri@eri-macro ~]$ pkg-config --exists bash --modversion
5.0-release
```

если установленна `-dev` версия пакета